# How to pass data in slug.js Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Nextjs, i am trying to integrate [slug.js] page, i want to know that how can we manage/get data in sidebar (similar blogs) ? in other words for blog details i used "get static path" and "props", But now i want to pass "current slug" ( to API) so i can fetch all blogs with this blog category,How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

### Client-side approach:

Since you pass the post as page-props via getStaticProps, you can either take the slug from there (if it's included in your data model), or extract the slug from the url via next's `useRouter` hook in case you want to do client-side fetching:

```
import axios from "axios"; // using axios as an example
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Component = () => {
  const [similarPosts, setSimilarPosts] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;

  const getSimilarPosts = async () => {
    if (!router.isReady() || !slug) return [];

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/similar-posts-route/" + slug);
    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (similarPosts.length > 0) return;

    (async () => {
      const posts = await getSimilarPosts(); // assuming API returns an array of posts as data.
      setSimilarPosts(posts);
    })();
  }, []);

  return <div>Similar posts: {JSON.stringify(similarPosts)}</div>;
};


[...]
```

### Server-Side approach (preferred):

I believe it would be a better approach to directly fetch similar posts inside `getStaticProps` to reduce API calls and for a better UX.

Inside `getStaticProps` you can take the slug from `context.params` and fetch all similar posts directly from your database/CMS, and pass them directly as props to your page component:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;

  // fetch similar posts directly from the database using the slug (don't call the API, it's not up yet during build phase)
  const similarPosts = await executeDatabaseQueryForSimilarPosts(slug);

  // [...] fetch the rest of the page props

  return {
    props: {
      similarPosts,

      // [...] return the rest of page props
    },
      revalidate: 60 * 30 // re-fetch the data at most every 30 minutes, so the posts stay up to date
  };
}

// directly take all similar posts from props

const Component = ({similarPosts}) => {
  return <div>Similar posts: {JSON.stringify(similarPosts)}</div>;
};
```